# How do you fix file permission error on AWS elastic beanstalk rails assets precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting the following error on AWS elastic beanstalk when running `bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile`:

```
Command failed with status (1): [/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby /opt/rubie...]
```

and at the stack trace displays:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/app/current/tmp/requirejs
```

I need to update the permissions so the rake task can write to this tmp folder. I would usually just run `chmod` or `chown` on the server to grant access to the user. However, I'm on elastic beanstalk and I don't believe that'll work on new instances and future deployments. What's the way fix this so it applies to all deployments on each EC2 instance?

Comment: Why the down vote? Should I provide more info?

Comment: I have this exact problem, did you ever solve it?

Comment: I got around it for the time being by precompiling the assets and committing in the repo before deploying. The deployment itself is faster also.

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed (see *worked around*) this using an eb extension command that creates the `tmp` folder and makes it writable:

```
# <project-root>/.ebextensions/fix_temporary_folder_permissions.yml
commands:
  01_set_tmp_permissions:
    command: "mkdir /var/app/ondeck/tmp; chmod 600 /var/app/ondeck/tmp"
```

**Note:** I'm not entirely sure how this works across multiple instances, but I imagine that they will all perform their own precompilation on deploy.

Comment: You might have to change the name to `fix_temporary_folder_permissions.config` if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I already have experienced about this.

You should run with `root` permission on current app folder `/var/app/current` following:

- `sudo su`
- `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`